# Alguien sabe porque me sale asi el datetime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

Alguna ayuda estoy trajando con asp.net mvc las tablas lo llamo con ajax[image]

[image]

Comment: Debes darle el formato que deseas mediante las funciones de JQuery, a menos que lo estes guardando y obteniendo como un string =/

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos la estructura de la tabla y la consulta que utilizas para obtener los datos?

Comment: Primero, nunca compartas código como imagen, ¿cómo esperas que lo copie para arreglarlo? :).  Segundo, estás iterando sobre los campos, puedes hacer la transformación directamente dentro de `$.each`.  Si tan solo tuviera el **texto** podría haber hecho el ejemplo directamente ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON no tiene un tipo de dato de fecha y el serializador de .net por defecto convierte los `DateTime` a ese formato que ves en forma de *string*.  Tienes algunas alternativas para tratar con eso:

1. Lo manejas en JavaScript

   Cuando recibes los datos en tu llamada ajax lo deserializas de esta manera:

   ```
   var data = JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) { 
       if (typeof value === 'string') { 
           var d = /\/Date\((\d*)\)\//.exec(value); 
           return (d) ? new Date(+d[1]) : value; 
       } 
       return value; 
   });
   ```

   la función `parse` opcionalmente recibe una función como segundo parámetro que te permite controlar cómo interpretar los datos.  En este ejemplo utiliza un regex para identificar los *strings* que tienen formato de fecha.
2. Le das formato en el controller antes de serializar

   En lugar de envíar propiedades `DateTime`, creas otro objeto que tenga una `string` con la fecha en el formato que desees.  No nos has mostrado el código de la acción que envía la data, si lo agregaras sería más fácil indicarte como hacerlo.
3. Utilizas un serializador alternativo

   Con un poco de configuración puedes la librería Json.NET que es más flexible y te permite elegir cómo serán serializadas las fechas, en formato Microsoft (`/Date(1542333807388)/`) o ISO (`2018-11-16T02:03:27.388Z`).

   Creas una clase derivada de `JsonResult`:

   ```
   public class CustomJsonResult : JsonResult
   {
       private const string _dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

       public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       {
           if (context == null)
           {
               throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
           }

           HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
           {
               response.ContentType = ContentType;
           }
           else
           {
               response.ContentType = "application/json";
           }
           if (ContentEncoding != null)
           {
               response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
           }
           if (Data != null)
           {
               // Using Json.NET serializer
               var isoConvert = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
               isoConvert.DateTimeFormat = _dateFormat;
               response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, isoConvert));
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   y luego en el controller la usas así:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Index() {
       return new CustomJsonResult { Data = new { fecha = DateTime.Now } };
   }
   ```

Comment: Si mira ya puse otra imagen haber si me puedes orientar gracias por la sugerencia